# Format the number from API in Angular

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, angular9

I get Km ranges from from ASP.NET Core API and would like to format the number with 1000 seperator like:
75,000 - 100,000 - 125,000 so on.
How do I achieve this with the following:

JSON output:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 8,
        "Km": 75000
    },
    {
        "Id": 9,
        "Km": 100000
    },
    {
        "Id": 10,
        "Km": 125000
    },
    {
        "Id": 11,
        "Km": 150000
    }
]
```

my KM model

```
export class KmRange {
    Id: number;
    Km: number;
}
```

my component:

```
dropdownList = [];
this.dropdownList = await this._service.getKmRanges().toPromise();
```

**EDIT - I AM USING IT LIKE THIS NOW**
[I cam accross this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)
it says regularexpression is faster than toLocaleString, so Im ended up using like this.

```
this.dropdownList = await this._service.getKmRanges().toPromise();
for (var i = 0; i < this.dropdownList.length; i++) {
  this.dropdownList[i].Km = this.toCommas(this.dropdownList[i].Km);
}

toCommas(value) {
  return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the numbers (or dates) using locales both in API and Angular.

The best is to let Angular handle the localization since it's run on client side, we don't need to put more work to API.

You can follow this to setup locales https://angular.io/guide/i18n

And use this as example to format number https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

UPDATE:

You can use template as listed in here (https://cuppalabs.github.io/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/#/templating)

```
<c-item>
      <ng-template let-item="item">
        <label>{{item.Km | number:1.0-3:'en-US'}}</label>
      </ng-template>
</c-item>
```

Comment: im confused.. in the mentioned example link they change in ngmodel, but in my case I need to change in array (dropdownList[]). how do I do that.

Comment: How do you use your dropdownList in html?

Comment: I am using https://openbase.io/js/angular2-multiselect-dropdown

Comment: I update the answer. I'm not sure what locale you want, how many decimal digits. I just put example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Number.prototype.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) with 'en-US' option.

```
result: string[] = dropdownList.map(x => x.toLocaleString('en-US'));
```

Comment: this.dropdownList = await (await this._service.getKmRanges().toPromise()).map(x => x.Km.toLocaleString("en-US")); // not working!